# Linq Mongodb Multiple sums as columns with where for each

Tags: .net, vb.net, mongodb, linq, aggregation-framework

I have a Mongo Doc as Follows

```
{
    userid: "jd",
    fullname: "john doe",
    Tracker : [
        { 
            type: "aaa",
            total: "111"
            state: "Active"
        }
        { 
            type: "bbb",
            total: "222"
            state: "Active"
        }
        { 
            type: "aaa",
            total: "333"
            state: "Active"
        }
        { 
            type: "ccc",
            total: "111"
            state: "Active"
        }
        {
            type: "ccc",
            total: "111"
            state: "Inactive"
        }
   ]
}
```

My goal is to have a linq query within vb.net (or c# that i can convert to vb.net) that sums up all the totals for each type, but in columns, not rows

```
userid    fullname    aaa    bbb   ccc 
jd        john doe     444   222   111
```

so far, I got:
Note: _users is my mongocollection

```
dim results = From u in _users.AsQueryable(Of MyClass)() _
Order by _u.fullname
Where _u.Tracker.Any(Function(typestate) typestate.state="Active"
Select _u.userid, _u.fullname, totalAAA = _u.Tracker.Sum(Function(tAAA) tAAA.total),  totalBBB = _u.Tracker.Sum(Function(tBBB) tBBB.total), totalCCC = _u.Tracker.Sum(Function(tCCC) tCCC.total)
```

I know that totalAAA, totalBBB and totalCCC will result in the same, I need a specific were clause for each of those, just don't know how to do it, or if there is a better way

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is the aggregation pipeline. Rather than an LINQ type of query it is constructed as a series of BSON documents. See your [documentation.](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.8.3/html/0dab751c-6534-9a3a-1348-70a2ebdff73f.htm)

The pipeline structure goes as follows:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$Tracker" }

    // Match the condition
    { "$match": { "Tracker.state": "active" } },

    // Project the output to new fields
    { "$project": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "firstname": 1,
        "aaa": { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$type", "aaa" ] },
            "$total",
            0
        ]},
        "bbb": { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$type", "bbb" ] },
            "$total",
            0
        ]}
        "ccc": { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$type", "ccc" ] },
            "$total",
            0
        ]}
    }},

    // Group the total 
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "user_id": "$user_id",
            "type": "$type",
        },
        "fullname": { "$first": "$fullname" },
        "aaa": { "$sum": "$aaa" },
        "bbb": { "$sum": "$bbb" },
        "ccc": { "$sum": "$ccc" }
    }},

    // Final projection to clear up
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "user_id": 1
        "fullname": 1,
        "aaa": 1,
        "bbb": 1,
        "ccc": 1
    }}
])
```

So this allows you to "unwind" and "match" the items in the document array so that only the required condition is selected. And then the document is "reshaped" through "$project", then finally "grouped" in order to sum the totals.

Comment: @user3146613 No problem. Glad to be of help. Your acceptance of my answer as always is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

THanks Neil,

I was attempting to adapt your example to my code, and it became very lengthy as i needed to add more "types" to it; i started to play with my original linq and got it to work

```
    dim results = From u in _users.AsQueryable(Of MyClass)() _
Order by _u.fullname
Where _u.Tracker.Any(Function(typestate) typestate.state="Active"
Select _u.userid, _u.fullname, _
 totalAAA = _u.Tracker.Where(Function(tAAA) tAAA.Type="aaa").Sum(Function(tAAA) tAAA.total), _
 totalBBB = _u.Tracker.Where(Function(tBBB) tBBB.Type="bbb").Sum(Function(tBBB) tBBB.total), _
 totalCCC = _u.Tracker.Where(Function(tCCC) tCCC.Type="ccc").Sum(Function(tCCC) tCCC.total)
```

That works out nicely and fairly fast; anything wrong with using my method as there is always more than one way to do things, any blind spots I would hit with the above linq?